# What is the expected number of empty boxes?

Tags: expectation, means

There are n boxes numbered 1 to n and n balls numbered 1 to n. The balls are to be randomly placed in a box (not necessarily different boxes). What is the expected number of empty boxes?

I tried that:

$ X_i=1$  means Empty boxes

$ X_i=0$  otherwise

$E(\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}E(X_i)$.

P.S. We have that $E(X_i)=P(\{X_i=1\})=(({n-1}/n)^{n})$ for $i=1,\dots,n$

So the $E(\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i)=n((({n-1})/n)^{n})$

I think I'm wrong but can't seem to get the correct idea.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think your answer is wrong?

Comment: because I'm looking for $E(X_i)$

Comment: should the expected number of boxes be $E(\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i)=n((({n-1})/n)^{n})$ ?

Comment: Yes, you're right! See the answer below for how to show it formally. I write $\mathbb{1}(A_k)$ instead of $X_k$ but they are the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For bin $k$, the probability no ball lands in this bin is $(1 - 1/n)^n$ by independence, since the probability the $i^{\text{th}}$ ball doesn't land there is $1 - 1/n$. Let $A_k$ denote the event that no ball lands in bin $k$. So we've computed that $\mathbb{P}(A_k) = (1-1/n)^n$.

The number of bins with no ball is $$\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}(A_k).$$
Thus the expected number of bins with no ball is
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}(A_k)\right] = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{1}(A_k)\right] = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}(A_k) = n(1-1/n)^n.$$